# Пушкинский, но ДарвинОВский

Tags: словообразование

***Пушкинский [праздник] но ДарвинОВский [музей]***.
Чуть было не спросил "почему так", хотя сам регулярно упрекал спрашивающих в том, что так вопрос обычно ставить неправильно, если нужно объяснение, а не причина.
Поставлю по-другому. *Есть тому какое-то рациональное объяснение?* Понятно, что Пушкин - наше всё, а Дарвин - таки иностранец. Но ведь суффикс ***ск(+ий)*** прекрасно лепится к любому словотипу: конский, например, или московский,  (хотя орловский).
Я пока не могу нащупать правила по которому это притяжательное ОВ (или ИН) вставляется перед -ский?
И еще. Краткой притяжательной формы прилагательных русские фамилии на -ОВ/-ИН нормативно не имеют, поскольку сами восходят к таким формам (хотя и несколько отличаются от них). Невозможно, например сказать "Пушкинов роман в стихах". Только "Пушкинский" (вопрос о заглавной - отдельная тема). Нормативно ли при этом "Дарвинов [закон]"? Или все-таки тут "Дарвинский"?

*А если Дарвин - Юрий Иванович? Или вот Чаплины - тоже "сладкая парочка". Кронин - вполне русская фамилия. С ними как?*

Comment: Как-нибудь так: если почему-либо их жёны на русский манер носят фамилии "Дарвина", "Чаплина" и "Кронина", то их семейные традиции уже "дарвинские" (дарвиных, а не дарвинов или дарвиновские), "чаплинские" (чаплиных, а не чаплинов) и "кронинские" (крониных, а не кронинов). В обратную сторону все меняется с превращением напр. Пушкина в "Пушкинда" (пушкиндовские, пушкиндов).

Comment: @Alex_ander, я, наверное, плохо вопрос задал. То, что Вы говоррите вещи более или менее известные. Да, с Чарльз Дарвин отличается от Юрия Ивановича Дарвина. Хотя бы по творительному падежу. *С Ч . Дарином, но с Ю. И. Дарвиным.* Гл влпрос-то не в этом.Когда вообще требуется суффикс -ов/-ин перед  "-ский", а когда он не требуется.  Ясно, что даже для имен нарицательных нет единого очевидного правила: орловский, битловскиий, Здесь-то чем "ов"  мотивировано?!  А если человек носит фамилию Татарин?

Answer (score 3):

Дарвиновский - не уникальное, а системное словообразование прилагательных, образованных от  иностранных имен Гершвин, Грин, Чаплин, Толкиен и т. д., которые воспринимаются как существительные. Все они образуются с помощью суффиксов -ов- и -ск-.

Русские фамилии на "-ов" и на "-ин" являются этимологическими образованиями от существительных.Ты кто?Чей сын?-Васин, Петин, Пушкин(сын человека с прозвищем Пушка). Исторически это притяжательные прилагательные.Сын Пушкина -пушкинский, музей имени Пушкина -Пушкинский.

Слово "Дарвин" русский язык видит не как фамилию, наподобие "Пушкин" или "Есенин". Это обычное для языка существительное типа "сплин", "сатин", "крепдешин" и тому подобные, единое целое, без суффикса -ин.

"Чей?" -  "Дарвин-ов"
Добавим : "из каких будешь?"  и получаем "Из  Дарвинов", то есть "Дарвинов-ский".

В современном языке формы могут различаться в зависимости от мотивирующего слова: Дарвинский - от Дарвин (город); Дарвиновский - от Дарвин (фамилия) (Валгина Н.С. Активные процессы в современном русском языке)

Но сейчас эти грани стираются. Вот,например, на официальном сайте: Да́рвинский госуда́рственный приро́дный биосфе́рный запове́дник — особо охраняемая природная территория в России. Расположен на территориях Череповецкого района Вологодской области и Брейтовского района Ярославской области.
http://fv-tour.ru/ru/russia/2859-darwin-reserve

И московский тоже иногда в справочниках имеет варианты:
Организационный отдел Дарвинского музея

http://fb.ru/article/148102/darvinskiy-muzey-v-moskve-muzey-darvina-moskva---adres  Дарвинский музей в Москве. Появляется как бы разговорный вариант, более "удобоваримый" для простых граждан, не вдумывающихся в словообразовательные законы.

Из акад. грамматики: 
 http://rusgram.narod.ru/609-645.html
 Морф -овск-, орфогр. также -евск- (фонемат. |ов1с2к|), выступает после согласных (кроме |к'|, |г'|, |х'|) в прилагательных, мотивированных:

а) некоторыми нарицательными сущ. муж. р. I скл. - немотивированными и с суф. морфами -ик, -их, -б ец: воровской, шутовской, отцовский,дедовский, жениховский, стариковский, портновский, борцовский, чертовский, бунтовской, банковский, кремлевский, съездовский,августовский; особенно тяготеют к сочетаемости с морфом -овск- основы на -ик и односложные основы: нов. битниковский; окказ.сочельниковская елка (Возн.), фрицевская телега (Нагиб.), сейфовские ключи (газ.);

б) личными именами муж. р. I скл., а также фамилиями и прозвищами различных типов склонения: Пётр - петровский, шекспировский, капабланковский, горьковский, геркулесовский, дарвиновский,гойевский, жюльверновский;

в) топонимами различных типов склонения: Днепр - днепровский, Орёл - орловский, Массандра - массандровский,Клинцы - клинцовский, Нагорье - нагорьевский; г) аббревиатурами - нарицательными и собственными (профорговский, детсадовский,уралмашевский); д) однословными названиями учреждений и предприятий, партий и других политических группировок, журналов и газет, спортивных обществ, кораблей и т. п., принадлежащими к различным типам склонения: "Калибр" (завод) - калибровский, Бунд - бундовский, "Искра" - искровский, "Зенит" - зенитовский, "Аврора" - авроровский; сравним: шахтёр (лицо, нариц.) - шахтёрский и "Шахтёр" (спортивное общество) - шахтёровский.

Примечание 1. Многие прилагательные, мотивированные существительными перечисленных здесь семантических групп, содержат морф -ск-: бетховенский,чаплинский, мефистофельский, донкихотский, оренбургский, камский, баскунчакский; комсомольский, горсоветский (наряду с горсоветовский); "Локомотив" -локомотивский, "Арсенал" (завод) - арсенальский. Только морф -ск- выступает в прилагательных, мотивированных русскими фамилиями на -ов(-ев), -ин (тургеневский,пушкинский), фамилиями на -ич (юденичский), русскими и другими славянскими топонимами с основами на -ов (-ев), -ин, -град, -город (ростовский, каневский, фрязинский,белградский, новгородский).

Comment: Людмила, это все, конечно правильно, но давно известно (кроме того, что наблюдается стирание различий - вот это для меня ново). Но на самом деле Вы меня только запутали. Давайте от печки. ***Фамилия Татарин или Жемчужин какую форму породит? Татариновский, Татаринский, Татаровский? Или вообще Татарский?*** И почему. Заметьте, что *Грин - очевидно Гриновский*. А потом фамилий, омонимичных именам нарицательным. Типа *Орел и Орлов, Сорока и Сорокин, Цапля и Цаплин*.

Comment: В акад. грамматике: http://rusgram.narod.ru/609-645.html  § 631  перечислены условия использования формантов -ск и -овск, и есть примечание: 1. .. Только морф -ск- выступает в прилагательных, мотивированных русскими фамилиями на -ов(-ев), -ин (тургеневский,пушкинский), фамилиями на -ич (юденичский), русскими и другими славянскими топонимами с основами на -ов (-ев), -ин, -град, -город (ростовский, каневский, белградский, новгородский). Получается, что от русских фамилий только -ск, а от нерусских - и -ск, и -овск

Comment: Фамилии Татарин не встречала, если только прозвище, это сущ. От него: Татаринов пиджак(индивидуальная принадлежность), татариновский и татаринский  дом, например. Жемчужин тоже как-то  не по-русски звучит фамилия, должно быть или Жемчугов(от жемчуг), или Жемчужинов(от жемчужина), от него жемчужиновский.

Comment: Есть такая фамилия. От "татара". Баргузин - вот это уж точно, зам знал. *Филин* - от Филя, Филимон. И от него *"филинский"* - мой язык ну никак не выговорит. Только *"филиновский"*  ***Татариновский* - а как же ваше правило, что от русских - без "-ов"?!** Я ж только ради этого и пример этот привел. Если в целом, то вы меня как раз убедили, что явных и однозначных правил тут нету. Видимо, есть некая статистика, но даже она плохо формулируется.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо огромное. Не могу сейчас продолжить. Ой, *Мордвин* - тоже фамилия. Очень распространенная.

Comment: Ну, насчёт "Татарин - русская" ещё бабушка надвое сказала, может русская, может нет, это всё-таки изначально от прозвища и суфф. -ин там как-то не вычленяется как притяжательный(только как показатель национальности)даже исторически, а правило касается русских с  притяжат. суфф.-ин.

Comment: *насчёт "Татарин - русская" ещё бабушка надвое сказала*,  Вроде как сибирская. К грузинской кухне отношение вряд ли имеет. Так что русская, не сомневайтесь. А фамилии - все от прозвищ.

Answer (score 1):

1)  **Для образования относительных прилагательных  используются суффиксы СК/ЕСК, ОВСК, ИНСК.** Если мотивирующим является нарицательное существительное, то выбор зависит **от основы:** мор/ск/ой, враж/еск/ий, старик/овск/ий, матер/инск/ий. Если мотивирующим является собственное имя (имена, фамилии, топонимы), то выбор суффикса **также зависит от основы**:  москов/ск/ий, чикаг/ск/ий, днепр/овск/ий, гёт/овск/ий, толст/овск/ий, ялт/инск/ий, екатерин/инск/ий.

Если относительное прилагательное образуется от лица, то в нем присутствует притяжательный формант ОВ или ИН (и вопрос в том, **нужно ли нам два форманта в одном слове).**

Также для собственных имен должно соблюдаться **еще одно условие: название должно быть узнаваемым (город, конкретное лицо и т. д.).**

2) **Почему правильно только «пушкинский», но не «пушкиновский»?**  Употребление суффикс ОВСК не является обоснованным,  добавление притяжательного форманта ОВ является лишним, и это относится ко всем русским фамилиям с суффиксом ИН.

Но тогда почему преимущественно используется прилагательное **дарвин/овск/ий** (дарвиновский эволюционный процесс, Дарвиновский музей, дарвиновский отбор), можно ли сказать: Вьюрок **дарвинский** не посрамил своего «крестного отца». [Б. Силкин. Пернатый мастер // «Вокруг света», 1968] ?

3) **Примечание (о суффиксе ОВ)**
Формант ОВ (притяжательный суффикс ОВ) использовался при образовании притяжательных  прилагательных  (братов, бригадиров, дедов, царёв, марксова теория, **шекспировы трагедии**), но в настоящее время суффикс ОВ применяется преимущественно для официальных  фамилий или приобретает просторечно-разговорный характер (поэтому сейчас чаще говорят «**шекспировские трагедии, шекспировские страсти**»). Притяжательный формант ОВ присутствует, и относительный суффикс СК также на месте.

4) **Итак, к выбору формы прилагательного не стоит подходить формально: оно должно быть фонетически благозвучным и по возможности точно указывать на мотивирующее имя собственное.** Дарвинский музей – это нормально (хорошая фонетика и понятное имя). В Австралии есть город Дарвин, но Австралия  от нас далеко, и не стоит из-за города Дарвина усложнять нашу речь. Чаплинский герой, чаплинский танец – это тоже  правильно (реже встречается «чаплиновский   характер»).
Татарский – от татары, татариновский – от Татариново,  Татаринский – обычно фамилия, а известного человека по фамилии Татарин нет, поэтому нет и  татаринского музея.

Answer (score 0):

В столице два музея, оба пушкинские. Один, что на Пречистенке — Пушкина, дом -музей, другой, на Волхонке, имени Пушкина. Последний не тянет на Пушкинский, Пушкин там не жил, не бывал, в его фондах нет ни единого музейного предмета, связанного с поэтом. Было бы справедливо и правильно называть его Пушкиновский. Однако и это скорее запутает ситуацию, чем наведёт порядок, с таким названием музей будут искать в Пушкине или Пушкино.

Comment: Я бы "пушкиновский" отнёс только к населённому пункту Пушкино - ради восстанавливаемости его названия из производного слова :)

Comment: Согласен, вариант не безупречный, но Богатырёву (директору музея на Пречистенке) он бы и такой подошёл. Ему очень надоела эта путаница.